# what is "sw $fp($sp)" mean in MIPS

Tags: cpu-architecture

I have an assignment in computer organization class.
 This is part of factorial recursion code in MIPS

```
main:
                                # prolog        
     sub     $sp, $sp, 4       
     sw      $_ra_, ($sp)
     sub     $sp, $sp, 4       
     sw      $_fp_, ($sp)

     sub     $fp, $sp, _8_     
     move    $sp, $fp
```

In this code, I know the meaning of "sub $sp, $sp, 4" ,store $ra
 and store frame pointer under the $ra register.However, I can not          understand the codes  "sw $fp,($sp)"  , "sub $fp, $sp,8" and 
"move $sp, $fp".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For the instruction "sw $fp,($sp)" sw means store word , you are storing a word in memory.Basically you are sending the contents of $fp into a memory address contained in the register $sp with zero offset.
2. For the instruction "sub $fp, $sp,8" you are subtracting 8 from the contents of the register $sp and you are taking the result in the register $fp.
3. For "move $sp, $fp" you are simply moving contents of register $fp into register $sp.